# CMake Error: Unknown CMake command "ocv_glob_modules"."

Tags: python, linux, opencv, ubuntu, cmake

I am trying to install opencv for a python project but I keep getting the following error -

```
"CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (ocv_glob_modules):
  Unknown CMake command "ocv_glob_modules"."
```

I tried to google it but couldn't get any help. I am working on Ubuntu 14.04 and have done all the installation (not the optional ones) given on page [Linux install guide for opencv](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html)

I'm using the same command given in the page to install

Please guide me through

Edit: I installed the opencv by the help from the comment but I still can't use it to code. Please reconsider this question. I'm getting the error

> "No module named cv2"

Comment: I see a lot of issues on here with open-cv and ubuntu 14.04, I installed 3.0.0-dev from source and I don't seem to have any issue so might be worth installing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for Ubuntu its simple to install:

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

Comment: Thanks It worked for me! Was I moving on the wrong track when trying the above method?

Answer (score 1):

I got that error because I configured the CMake source directory to /opencv-VERSION/modules. Just fixing it to /opencv-VERSION made the error go away.